# How to ignore code documentation in .meteor directory with meteor-jsdoc

Tags: javascript, meteor, jsdoc

I want to use [meteor-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-jsdoc) to document my source code. After installing it, I did `meteor-jsdoc build` and `meteor-jsdoc start`.

I opened the documentation at `http://localhost:3333` and noticed that there are a bunch of functions etc. already documented:

```
// 2
// 2
// 2
// 500
// 500
// 500
// 507
// 507
// 507
// 515
// 515
// 515
// 6
// 6
// 6
<anonymous>~Blaze
<anonymous>~Blaze.Each
<anonymous>~Blaze.Each
<anonymous>~Blaze.If
<anonymous>~Blaze.If
<anonymous>~Blaze.Template
<anonymous>~Blaze.Template
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#$
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#$
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#autorun
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#autorun
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#find
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#find
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#findAll
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#findAll
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#subscribe
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#subscribe
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#subscriptionsReady
<anonymous>~Blaze.TemplateInstance#subscriptionsReady
<anonymous>~Blaze.Unless
<anonymous>~Blaze.Unless
<anonymous>~Blaze.View
<anonymous>~Blaze.View
<anonymous>~Blaze.With
<anonymous>~Blaze.With
<anonymous>~Blaze.currentView
<anonymous>~Blaze.currentView
<anonymous>~Blaze.getData
<anonymous>~Blaze.getData
<anonymous>~Blaze.getView
<anonymous>~Blaze.getView
<anonymous>~Blaze.isTemplate
<anonymous>~Blaze.isTemplate
<anonymous>~Blaze.remove
<anonymous>~Blaze.remove
<anonymous>~Blaze.render
<anonymous>~Blaze.render
<anonymous>~Blaze.renderWithData
<anonymous>~Blaze.renderWithData
<anonymous>~Blaze.toHTML
<anonymous>~Blaze.toHTML
<anonymous>~Blaze.toHTMLWithData
<anonymous>~Blaze.toHTMLWithData
<anonymous>~DDP
<anonymous>~DDP.connect
<anonymous>~DDP.connect
<anonymous>~EJSON
<anonymous>~EJSON.addType
<anonymous>~EJSON.addType
<anonymous>~EJSON.clone
<anonymous>~EJSON.clone
<anonymous>~EJSON.equals
<anonymous>~EJSON.equals
<anonymous>~EJSON.fromJSONValue
<anonymous>~EJSON.fromJSONValue
<anonymous>~EJSON.isBinary
<anonymous>~EJSON.isBinary
<anonymous>~EJSON.newBinary
<anonymous>~EJSON.newBinary
<anonymous>~EJSON.parse
<anonymous>~EJSON.parse
<anonymous>~EJSON.stringify
<anonymous>~EJSON.stringify
<anonymous>~EJSON.toJSONValue
<anonymous>~EJSON.toJSONValue
<anonymous>~Match
<anonymous>~Match.test
<anonymous>~Match.test
<anonymous>~Meteor
<anonymous>~Meteor.Error
<anonymous>~Meteor.Error
<anonymous>~Meteor.absoluteUrl
<anonymous>~Meteor.absoluteUrl
<anonymous>~Meteor.isClient
<anonymous>~Meteor.isServer
<anonymous>~Meteor.release
<anonymous>~Meteor.release
<anonymous>~Meteor.settings
<anonymous>~Meteor.startup
<anonymous>~Mongo
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#allow
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#allow
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#deny
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#deny
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#upsert
<anonymous>~Mongo.Collection#upsert
<anonymous>~Mongo.Cursor
<anonymous>~Mongo.Cursor
<anonymous>~Mongo.ObjectID
<anonymous>~Mongo.ObjectID
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#get
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#get
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#get
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#set
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#set
<anonymous>~ReactiveVar#set
<anonymous>~Template#events
<anonymous>~Template#events
<anonymous>~Template#events
<anonymous>~Template#helpers
<anonymous>~Template#helpers
<anonymous>~Template#helpers
<anonymous>~Template
<anonymous>~Template.body
<anonymous>~Tracker
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#invalidate
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#invalidate
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#onInvalidate
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#onInvalidate
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#stop
<anonymous>~Tracker.Computation#stop
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#changed
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#changed
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#depend
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#depend
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#hasDependents
<anonymous>~Tracker.Dependency#hasDependents
<anonymous>~Tracker.active
<anonymous>~Tracker.active
<anonymous>~Tracker.afterFlush
<anonymous>~Tracker.afterFlush
<anonymous>~Tracker.autorun
<anonymous>~Tracker.autorun
<anonymous>~Tracker.currentComputation
<anonymous>~Tracker.currentComputation
<anonymous>~Tracker.flush
<anonymous>~Tracker.flush
<anonymous>~Tracker.nonreactive
<anonymous>~Tracker.nonreactive
<anonymous>~Tracker.onInvalidate
<anonymous>~Tracker.onInvalidate
Blaze // 2
Blaze // 2
Blaze // 2
Blaze
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 242#view // 241
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 242#view // 241
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 253#firstNode // 252
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 253#firstNode // 252
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 263#lastNode // 262
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 263#lastNode // 262
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 160#data // 161
Blaze.TemplateInstance // 160#data // 161
DDP // 2
DDP // 2
DDP // 2
DDP // 2
EJSON
EJSON.CustomType // 21#typeName // 20
EJSON.CustomType // 21#typeName // 20
EJSON.CustomType // 29#toJSONValue // 28
EJSON.CustomType // 29#toJSONValue // 28
EJSON.CustomType // 37#clone // 36
EJSON.CustomType // 37#clone // 36
EJSON.CustomType // 45#equals // 44
EJSON.CustomType // 45#equals // 44
IterationCallback
IterationCallback
IterationCallback
Match // 41
Match // 41
Match // 41
Meteor // 1008
Meteor // 1008.disconnect
Meteor // 1316
Meteor // 1316.onConnection
Meteor // 1387
Meteor // 1387.publish
Meteor // 1455
Meteor // 1455.methods
Meteor // 466
Meteor // 466.subscribe
Meteor // 655
Meteor // 655.call
Meteor // 693
Meteor // 693.apply
Meteor // 986
Meteor // 986.status
Meteor // 998
Meteor // 998.reconnect
Meteor // 1008
Meteor // 1008.disconnect
Meteor // 466
Meteor // 466.subscribe
Meteor // 655
Meteor // 655.call
Meteor // 693
Meteor // 693.apply
Meteor // 986
Meteor // 986.status
Meteor // 998
Meteor // 998.reconnect
Meteor // 3
Meteor // 3
Meteor // 22
Meteor // 22.setTimeout
Meteor // 22.setTimeout
Meteor // 33
Meteor // 33.setInterval
Meteor // 33.setInterval
Meteor // 44
Meteor // 44.clearInterval
Meteor // 44.clearInterval
Meteor // 54
Meteor // 54.clearTimeout
Meteor // 54.clearTimeout
Meteor // 84
Meteor // 84.wrapAsync
Meteor // 84.wrapAsync
MethodInvocation // 30#isSimulation // 29
MethodInvocation // 30#isSimulation // 29
MethodInvocation // 48#userId // 47
MethodInvocation // 48#userId // 47
MethodInvocation // 63#connection // 62
MethodInvocation // 63#connection // 62
MethodInvocation // 79#unblock
MethodInvocation // 79#unblock
MethodInvocation // 91#setUserId
MethodInvocation // 91#setUserId
MethodInvocation // 30#isSimulation // 29
MethodInvocation // 30#isSimulation // 29
MethodInvocation // 48#userId // 47
MethodInvocation // 48#userId // 47
MethodInvocation // 63#connection // 62
MethodInvocation // 63#connection // 62
MethodInvocation // 79#unblock
MethodInvocation // 79#unblock
MethodInvocation // 91#setUserId
MethodInvocation // 91#setUserId
Mongo
Mongo.Collection // 420#insert // 419
Mongo.Collection // 420#insert // 419
Mongo.Collection // 430#update // 429
Mongo.Collection // 430#update // 429
Mongo.Collection // 444#remove // 443
Mongo.Collection // 444#remove // 443
Mongo.Collection // 256#find // 255
Mongo.Collection // 256#find // 255
Mongo.Collection // 282#findOne // 281
Mongo.Collection // 282#findOne // 281
Mongo.Cursor // 156#forEach // 154
Mongo.Cursor // 156#forEach // 154
Mongo.Cursor // 192#map // 190
Mongo.Cursor // 192#map // 190
Mongo.Cursor // 207#fetch // 208
Mongo.Cursor // 207#fetch // 208
Mongo.Cursor // 224#count // 225
Mongo.Cursor // 224#count // 225
Mongo.Cursor // 301#observe
Mongo.Cursor // 301#observe
Mongo.Cursor // 313#observeChanges
Mongo.Cursor // 313#observeChanges
Npm
Npm.require
Session // 19
Session // 19.setDefault // 20
Session // 29
Session // 29.get // 30
Session // 42
Session // 42.equals // 43
Session // 7
Session // 7.set // 8
Subscription // 1089#error
Subscription // 1089#error
Subscription // 1107#stop
Subscription // 1107#stop
Subscription // 1119#onStop
Subscription // 1119#onStop
Subscription // 1142#added
Subscription // 1142#added
Subscription // 1160#changed
Subscription // 1160#changed
Subscription // 1177#removed
Subscription // 1177#removed
Subscription // 1196#ready
Subscription // 1196#ready
Subscription // 874#connection // 873
Subscription // 874#connection // 873
Subscription // 915#userId // 916
Subscription // 915#userId // 916
Template // 475
Template // 475.instance // 474
Template // 475.instance // 474
Template // 68#onCreated // 66
Template // 68#onCreated // 66
Template // 68#onCreated // 66
Template // 80#onRendered // 78
Template // 80#onRendered // 78
Template // 80#onRendered // 78
Template // 92#onDestroyed // 90
Template // 92#onDestroyed // 90
Template // 92#onDestroyed // 90
Template // 182#created // 180
Template // 182#created // 180
Template // 182#created // 180
Template // 198#rendered // 196
Template // 198#rendered // 196
Template // 198#rendered // 196
Template // 211#destroyed // 209
Template // 211#destroyed // 209
Template // 211#destroyed // 209
Template // 3
Template // 3.dynamic // 4
Tracker // 6
Tracker // 6
Tracker // 6
Tracker
Tracker.Computation // 166#stopped // 168
Tracker.Computation // 166#stopped // 168
Tracker.Computation // 177#invalidated // 179
Tracker.Computation // 177#invalidated // 179
Tracker.Computation // 189#firstRun // 191
Tracker.Computation // 189#firstRun // 191
Tracker.ComputationFunction
Tracker.ComputationFunction
```

I guess, that meteor-jsdoc also used the source code in my `.meteor` directory. How can I ignore it?

Furthermore, I noticed that my site title changed to **Meteor Project Docs**.

Any idea how I can get my old site title back?

Answer (score 0):

I  went through the documentation and recognized your question while reading it.

Here on this page is your answer.
http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html

You have to modify the **conf.json** file for JSDoc like this:

```
"source": {
    "include": [ /* array of paths to files to generate documentation for */ ],
    "exclude": [ /* array of paths to exclude */ ],
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc)?$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
}
```

The conf.json is generated when you init a JSDoc project.

I do not have an answer for *"Furthermore, I noticed that my site title changed to Meteor Project Docs. Any idea how I can get my old site title back?"*

I hope it can help.